# Python: enumerate a slice with negative indices

Tags: python, loops, slice, python-itertools, enumeration

I want to iterate over and enumerate the last few items of a list:

`a = [1,2,3,4,5]`

`[c for c, i in enumerate(a[-3:], -3)]`  gives:
 `[-3, -2, -1]`

`[c for c, i in enumerate(list(a[-3:]))]`  gives:
`[0, 1, 2]`

`[c for c, i in islice(enumerate(a), -5)]`  raises:

```
ValueError: Indices for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= sys.maxsize.
```

So how do I get enumerated:
`[3, 4, 5]` using negative indices
?

**Example:**

`for i, j in enumerate(...): print(i,j)` where `...` contains a slice expression with only negative indices should give:

```
0 3
1 4
2 5
```

Comment: I think it's `enumerate(a[-3:], 3)` but not sure why you would have overlooked that, so maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Yes, I want to do it only using negative indices.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for. Could you edit the question to include the output you want?

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer if you use strings instead of numbers in `a`.  I still don't understand what you mean here.  Do you want `enumerate(a, -len(a))` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

print ([c for c in a[-3:]])
```

Output:

```
[3,4,5]
```

With enumerate:

```
print ([(i, j)[1] for i, j in enumerate(a[-3:])])
```

Comment: This is is clear but my question is how to get this slice enumerated.

Comment: You want to specifically use enumerate. With no more goal than this? See my edit.

Comment: Why would anyone do this?  It's the same as `a[-3:]`.

Comment: The OP wants. So the OP is right. Still I concede ;)

Answer (score 0):

`[c for c, i in enumerate(a[-3:], -3)]`  gives:  `[-3, -2, -1]`

you should get i not c

`[i for c, i in enumerate(a[-3:], -3)]` this will gives you `[3, 4, 5]`

Comment: c is the index,  i is the value in array.